# CryptAcquireContext returns 0x80090016 (NTE_BAD_KEYSET) on Windows Server 2022

Tags: windows, winapi, rsacryptoserviceprovider

Have an older in-house software that's been working fine for years on Server 2012, 2016, 2019. Recently, upgraded servers to 2022 and now following function is failing

CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProvider, NULL, MS_STRONG_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_SILENT)

GetLastError() returns 0x80090016 (NTE_BAD_KEYSET)

The app is being run from an administrator account, even tried with administrator priviledges

Comment: set breakpoint in `rsaenh.dll` on function `MyCreateFile` - look for second parameter - win32 file path to container. and result of `CreateFileW`

Comment: I don't have debugging setup on server. Is there a way to get this info via ProcMon?

Comment: are you can run custom tools here ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/cryptacquirecontext-troubleshooting

Comment: Possible reasons for the NTE_BAD_KEYSET (0x80090016) error:
1, Key container does not exist.
2, You do not have access to the key container.
3, The Protected Storage Service is not running.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT I've never had to create a Key container before. How do I check if its there or create it manually without changing the code?

Comment: @HansPassant Is there a cmdline/powershell way of creating a default key container?

Comment: I used example code here but removed container name (passed NULL). It generated key container, now the software is running fine.